# How can one move the arc in the every pic quotes construction in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering, stanli

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \begin{scope}[dashed]
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    \end{scope}
    %displaced points
    \point{delta_begin}{.5}{.5};
    \point{delta_end}{5.5}{1};
    %displaced beam
    \beam{2}{delta_begin}{delta_end};
    %virtual displacements
    \dimensioning{2}{begin}{delta_begin}{0}[$\delta y$];
    \dimensioning{1}{begin}{delta_begin}{.5}[$\delta x$];
    \draw
      [dashed] (delta_begin) -- (5.5, .5);
    %angle
    \coordinate (A) at (5.5, .5);
    \coordinate (B) at (delta_begin);
    \coordinate (C) at (delta_end);
    \pic[draw, angle radius = 10mm, "$\varphi$"] {angle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

I have a very small angle. The phi didn't fit between the lines. So the phi and the arc should to move to the right. The description of the `every pic quotes` construction you can find in section 18.2.1 on page 255 of the `TikZ & PGF` manual. Or is it better to use here the `arc` construction (section 14.7 on page 152).

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Change `angle radius`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angle radius` changes, surprisingly, the radius of the angle. Less obviously, `angle eccentricity` affects the placement of the label relative to the line marking the angle.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %the points
    \point{begin}{0}{0};
    \point{end}{5}{0};
    %the beam
    \begin{scope}[dashed]
      \beam{2}{begin}{end};
    \end{scope}
    %displaced points
    \point{delta_begin}{.5}{.5};
    \point{delta_end}{5.5}{1};
    %displaced beam
    \beam{2}{delta_begin}{delta_end};
    %virtual displacements
    \dimensioning{2}{begin}{delta_begin}{0}[$\delta y$];
    \dimensioning{1}{begin}{delta_begin}{.5}[$\delta x$];
    \draw
      [dashed] (delta_begin) -- (5.5, .5);
    %angle
    \coordinate (A) at (5.5, .5);
    \coordinate (B) at (delta_begin);
    \coordinate (C) at (delta_end);
    \pic[draw, angle radius = 30mm, angle eccentricity=1.2, "$\varphi$"] {angle};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: less squished angle]

Comment: Hello @cfr! Thank you for your answer! Shame on me. I don't know what I'am thougt about. But nice to know about the `angle eccentricity`!

Comment: @Su-47 It is always easier to see the obvious in other people's code :-).